# Where to filter state?

Tags: filter, angular, ngrx

Newbie question: I have an angular2 app using ngrx, I have a service that returns the state (array of observables) to a component.

My question is where do I filter the state if I want a read only subset of it to be used in the component?

Do I do it in the reducer, service, or component?

Answer (score 3):

Some guidance can be found in the [ngrx example application](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app). There is a pattern in which selectors are defined [alongside reducers](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/3171428285ca701595f97a8867476857c32571f9/src/reducers/books.ts#L61-L72):

```
/**
 * Because the data structure is defined within the reducer it is optimal to
 * locate our selector functions at this level. If store is to be thought of
 * as a database, and reducers the tables, selectors can be considered the
 * queries into said database. Remember to keep your selectors small and
 * focused so they can be combined and composed to fit each particular
 * use-case.
 */
export function getBookEntities() {
  return (state$: Observable<BooksState>) => state$
    .select(s => s.entities);
};
```

And those selectors are [used in (smart) components](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/3171428285ca701595f97a8867476857c32571f9/src/pages/collection.ts#L31-L33) to select/filter the state:

```
...
export class CollectionPage {

  books$: Observable<BooksInput>;

  constructor(store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.books$ = store.let(getBookCollection());
  }
}
```

This pattern/mechanism could be used to filter the state in either components or services - whichever best suits your architecture.